# binding annotation by coredata entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i use below code to binding Annotation in map with "contacts" entity

```
//add each object in Contacts entity to map view
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"name"]);

    //initializetion latitude and longitude
    aLng=[[info  valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
    aLat=[[info  valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];

    //if latitude and longitude not null
    if(aLng && aLat && aLng!=0.0 &&aLat!=0.0)
    {
        //create a new Coordinate
        CLLocationCoordinate2D wimLocation;
        wimLocation.latitude=aLat;
        wimLocation.longitude=aLng;

        //create a new Annotation and initializetion it
        MKPointAnnotation * myAnnotation=[MKPointAnnotation alloc];
        myAnnotation.coordinate=wimLocation;
        myAnnotation.title=[info valueForKey:@"name"];


        //add create Annotation to mapview
        [self.mapview addAnnotation:myAnnotation];

    }    
}
```

and its work very well but i have to problem 1- i want to show

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[info valueForKey:@"photo"]]
```

instead of pin image  2- how can i get selected contact(annotation) on map to do some actions

Answer (score 0):

Use an [MKAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/index.html) and set its `image` property.

Comment: Please put your answers according to my code,it just show one of photos i want to show all info photos